# Is it possible to change the caret-color of a textarea to *two* colors?

Tags: html, css, caret

I did some research and found you can change the caret-color of a textarea/input to any color you'd like, but is it possible to change it into 2 different colors?

I tried using the CSS `linear-gradient` function, but that doesn't seem to work:

```css
textarea {
      caret-color: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 255, 0), rgb(0, 0, 0));
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

whereas solid colors work

```css
textarea {
      caret-color: red;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color), only possible values for vanilla CSS-based `caret-color` are colors represented as RGB, RGBA, HSL, HSLA or HWB values **or** name colors, e.g. `black`. Gradients are not allowed by specifications.